# Compare time1 (from API request) against time2 (SQL request)

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, compare

I need to compare two times. The first time i receive from an API and has following format:

```
time_api = ["2021-03-17T22:15:56.4477742Z","2020-04-28T08:12:17.0722131Z"]
```

As the result i receive is a list containing more timestamps, I have written here a list with just two elements as an example.

The second time i receive from a SQL table and has following format:

```
time_sql = "2021-03-17 22:15:56.4477742"
```

A comparison on a string basis won´t work

```
if time_sql in time_api:
    print("foo")
```

I have had a glance into these methods, but i do not understand them yet fully:

- datetime.fromtimestamp(time_api[0])
- datetime.datetime(time_api[0])

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it is not clear whether you want to convert the inputs to a time / date representation before comparing -

If you want to compare them as strings - then you could do something like:

```
time_api_modified = [_.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '') for _ in time_api]
time_api_modified
# ['2021-03-17 22:15:56.4477742', '2020-04-28 08:12:17.0722131']

time_sql = "2021-03-17 22:15:56.4477742"
time_sql in time_api_modified
# True
```

If you do want to convert to a time or date representation before comparing, then you can look at using the `dateutil` library -

```
from dateutil.parser import *
time_api_modified = [parse(_, ignoretz=True) for _ in time_api]
time_sql = parse(time_sql)
time_sql in time_api_modified
# True
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Which method is faster and more reliable, if the list of time-stamps/strings from the API contains more than 50 positions?

Comment: The string comparison should be faster, although for comparison of lists of size ~50 - the  difference between these methods would be insignificant compared to the time taken to fetch from the API or Database. I am not sure what you mean by reliability here